# C# Using IComparer to sort alphanumeric list

Tags: c#, icomparer

I recently stumbled upon IComparer and I think it can help me sort my alphanumeric string list. 
//    "STATE-ShipSpeed-0001"

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>{
"TX-S3-1005",
"CA-S3-1205",
"NV-S2-1001",
"LA-S5-1015",
"VA-S1-1305",
};
```

From what I've read IComparer should be able to sort the list above in order, but I have absolutely no idea where to being. Could someone assist or help me?

Comment: What would be the desired outcome...

Comment: [How to use the IComparable and IComparer interfaces in Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320727)

Comment: How about you start with the MSDN documentation for `IComparer<T>`, and look at the example given there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See code below:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>{
"TX-S3-1005",
"CA-S3-1205",
"NV-S2-1001",
"LA-S5-1015",
"VA-S1-1305",
};

sortedList = myList.OrderBy(s => s).ToList();
```